# Is there a way to qualify the difficulty of solving nonlinearprogramming?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am looking for a way to qualify the difficulty of the resolution of a nonliner programming. In other words, what let us say that, for two nonlinear programmings involving the same nature of function, a problem is more difficult than the other.

For example in solving linear systems, the conditionning number of the matrix is a good indicator about the difficulty.

I am looking for indicators involving for exapmple: the magnitude of Lagrange multipliers, magnitudes of active constraints gradients, Hessian matrices...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tend to watch the number of nonlinear nonzero elements in the Jacobian as a measure of nonlinearity in my large scale NLPs.

Comment: Thank you for your repsponse. Could you explain more please?? Do yoi mean the Jacobian of the active constraints at the solution?

Comment: No, I meant just NLNZ of the (sparse) Jacobian (i.e. something we can observe before solving). The best measure after solving is of course solution time.

Comment: Solution time could be in fact a good measure but I'd like to construct optimization problems with different difficulties this is why I need a measure of difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

The real difficulty of (non-convex) nonlinear programming tends to be global rather than local in nature.  That is, is often quite easy for a solver to converge to a local optimum, but this might not be the global optimum.  One might consider how many
local optima there are and how high and wide are the barriers between them.
Unfortunately, for interesting problems it tends to be at least as difficult to measure those quantities as it is to find the optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. When I said the problems are of the same nature, this could mean that they are both nonlinear non convex. For my question the difficulty means finding a solution: a local minimum. In the book numerical optimization of Nocedal, the author made a link between the value of Lagrange multipliers and something he calles sensitivity of the objective function. This not exactly what I want but I wonder if there is something similar that qualifies the difficulty.